# fine uploader - freeform - expression engine

Tags: html, expressionengine, fine-uploader, freeform

i have a form created in 'freeform' that uses the 'file browse' input to allow people to upload an image file. thing is we'd like to give some feedback to the users regarding how much of the file has uploaded so i thought using 'fine uploader' would be a good start. we're also using 'expression engine' as our CMS.

the thing is i have no idea how to implement 'fine uploader' with 'EE' or 'freeform'. does any one have any tips ? can i wrap fine uploader around the 'input file' tag ? and how can i direct 'fine uploader' to our 'freeform' ee extension ?

any help would be appreciated! :D

thanks!

---

an example of what we have working at the moment..

```
{exp:freeform:form                                
form:name="photocomp"
form_name="photo_contest_2013"
form:id="2"
ajax="no"
error_page="forms/submit_errors" 
matching_fields="email"
return="forms/submit_success"
}
<input class="required" type="text" class="input_large" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">

<input type="file" name="upload_photo_1[0]" id="upload_photo_10" size="40">

<button class="altButton" value="donate" type="submit" name="submit" title="submit">Let's do this!</button>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with FreeForm or ExpressionEngine.  How do you use these tools?  Have you written a server-side component that handles requests from FreeForm, or do you simply use FreeForm to create a form and the FreeForm service handles the rest for you?

Comment: freeform basically sort out the administrator of form task.. so it will store all returned email addresses, files, messages etc in expresssion engine but give you a GUI to them. it also makes making forms easier as you end up using a mixture of normal form tags and template tags to call the fields. 

i suppose im trying to work out how i plug the functionality of 'fineuploader' into freeform .. at the moment im using a simple file input tag like this to allow the user to upload a picture..
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40"> which is inside a form tag

Comment: Have you written a server-side component that handles requests from FreeForm, or do you simply use FreeForm to create a form and the FreeForm service handles the rest for you?  Where are the submitted forms sent, specifically?

Comment: yeah.. so freeform handles the mailing of email to whoever filled out the form and also collects any files that are added to the form.. you end up putting normal form markup on the page though as the ids/names tie up with the vars in 'freeform' .. im just trying to work out how i replace the 'input file' with something like 'fineuploader' so the user gets some visual feedback whilst uploading a large file

Comment: an example of what we have working at the moment..

`{exp:freeform:form                                
form:name="photocomp"
form_name="photo_contest_2013"
form:id="2"
ajax="no"
error_page="forms/submit_errors" 
matching_fields="email"
return="forms/submit_success"
}
<input class="required" type="text" class="input_large" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">

<input type="file" name="upload_photo_1[0]" id="upload_photo_10" size="40">

<button class="altButton" value="donate" type="submit" name="submit" title="submit">Let's do this!</button>

{/exp:freeform:form}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Fine Uploader will be able to help you here as its not clear how or even if it can be integrated with FreeForm.  You will likely need to discuss your requirements with the people at FreeForm.  Fine Uploader would need to send the files to FreeForm's server (I assume), and FreeForm would have to respond according to Fine Uploader's defined response convention (e.g. {success: true}).

Comment: i've posted a question with the freeform guys.. freeform is an extension to expression engine so it uses EE's built in send mail and database.. thanks for the help though! will see what they say :D